# Keep PHP functions in RAM

Tags: php, function, ram

I have a php-file on my server that contains lots of static php functions - and they are loaded every time someone visits a page on my website. Unfortunatelly, loading them every time takes approximatelly 10%-30% of the whole execution time for my webpage.

Like I said, these functions are global and needed on every page - basically just like the normal PHP functions (e.g. `rand()`, `die()`, `microtime()`). And as far as I know, loading *these* functions doesn't take up any performance speed. I guess they're saved somewhere in RAM, Apache or whatsoever - I'm not an expert at this point.

However, is there a way to tell my server to keep my own global functions in mind for every PHP page? Without having to load them every time?

Comment: Are you already using something like [`APC`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.apc.php)?

Comment: No, I have never heard of it. Can you short summarize the advantages? Or explain what it does?

Comment: I think [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29) does it better thank I could :)

Comment: Oh, okay I see! Well this seems interesting. Does this allow me to cache specificly my PHP-file with all the function or does it automatically interfer with every other php-files, too? I'm just a bit afraid of possible disadvantages

Comment: By default it will cache and speed every file up, although you can set filters to exclude files. Haven't used it for a while, but it'd be my "go to" for speeding up PHP.

Comment: Okay, good. Still I don't see any disadvantages? I'd just like to make sure before I install something - I highly appreciate your help though. thanks!

Comment: HHVM is the future, many benchmarks have proven that it beats APC and Zephir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP APC (Alternative PHP Cache)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

The way PHP works is the server compiles PHP to byte code and then executes it.

The benefit of APC is that it caches the byte code and re-uses it for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thank you very much! My loading time for all the php functions decresed from approx. 0.0050s to 0.0002s! Very awesome, thanks

Comment: Since PHP 5.5, apc removed in favor of the opcache (aka Zend optimizer+) You may want to read about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php Also there are another extension (Apcu) still provides data (object) caching functionality of the good old apc. Here is the repository: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking may not be possible using pure PHP. You may checkout HACK(from FB). 
if you just want to make your page load faster. You can just replace the rand() function from your code. It will make you site load faster. Find a suitable alternative to rand() function and replace rand.